# Why do I feel like I'm working very hard yet feel very unproductive?

Tags: software-development, productivity, time-management, stress, mental-health

I'm a software developer and think myself very fortunate as I really enjoy writing code and learning about it and feel confident in my abilities. When I finish what I wanted to do for the day I feel fantastic and end the day on a high.

However I often feel very stressed at my job as most the time I'll finish the day and feel very unproductive despite working very hard and I'm paranoid that my colleagues think I'm sitting around all day doing nothing as I often fail to deliver my work on time.

I generally see myself as being a bit slow and would like to remedy either my perception of feeling slow or the reality whichever it may be so I can feel less stressed and enjoy my work more.

### Why I feel like I’m slow

- I rarely get what I aimed to do during the day done
- I rarely finish my story for the sprint
- I’ve less lines of code committed on my repo than most my colleagues
- A colleague once told me I have a habit of going out of scope and being a bit slow, although generally I'm a bit paranoid others think it too.

### What I've done to try and remedy feeling unproductive

- Implemented GTD via Evernote
- Use the Pomodoro technique every day
- Come in earlier and skip mid-day coffee breaks
- Learnt to touch type
- Learnt shortcuts for every tool I use
- Use Qbserve to track everything I do on my computer
- Use StayFocused to block all sites non work related within working hours
- Set Do Not Disturb mode on my phone between 9-5

---

## Example day

For the purpose of identifying where I'm going wrong for this post and for asking for help in general I've combed through my emails, Qbserve, commit and chat history to identify what I did on a day when I felt absolutely terrible when I left work yet felt exhausted from working hard. (feel free to skip this it's long)

#### What I wanted to do that day (I finished neither of these things)

1. Adjust my current code so one of the arrays keeps weak references to its elements using existing class in another of my companies frameworks
2. Create spreadsheet of expenses and send it to HR

#### Log of what I actually did

- Done a review of what I need to get done during the day and when I’ll do it.
- Attended sprint planning
- Looked at existing code in other framework I wanted to use to see if it’s suitable
- Looked online for other patterns that may be neater
- Looked at where it’s currently used and determined it would be too much work to transplant this.
- Converted array I was working with to a Set
- Wrote an email to our architect to check what framework
- Moving a duplicated class from one app and one framework in to another framework, unifying the functionality and adjusting the import
- Researched if there was a way to move this class without losing it’s git history
- Went through emails
- Messaged HR about my stock options which appeared to have evaporated
- Moved code to another prototype framework at architects request
- Tried to debug why code wouldn’t build and identified it was likely the new framework to blame
- Discussed problem with Architect
- Moved class back to the original framework I moved it to and adjusted code again so it would work there
- Reviewed stories to be groomed prior to backlog meeting
- Attended backlog grooming meeting
- Manually tested if current code works
- Researching if there’s a way to reverse popping a git stash
- Abandoned reversing the pop and fixed the conflicts between my uncommitted changes and stash
- Fixing a test that was already broke in a prototype framework I needed to move my code too.
- Moving all the framework I’m working on and the app that uses it to master to test if a bug I found is my doing
- Looking up the right person to contact about the bug in production
- Creating screenshots and a guide on how to reproduce the problem then emailing it.
- Partially went over a PR a colleague had done for me containing tests for some of the code I’m modifying and determined I’d need a longer look
- Attempted to remove what I thought was an unnecessary protocol
- Attempted to debug code, looked up problem and realised protocol was necessary
- Integrated new class in to my existing code
- Reversed array back to an array after realizing I’d need to modify the Weak array to be hashable and didn’t have time.
- Attempted to find clean way to automatically review nil references from array periodically and implemented it
- Wrote prints and placed breakpoints to attempt to see whether the array removed the weak references when deallocated but the app I was testing on would never use them.
- Attempted to build another one of our apps that would be a better test but it wouldn’t build and gave up.
- Reviewed my branch prior to creating a PR
- Updated documentation
- Wrote a list of improvements for the branch to do tomorrow morning

#### Total time spent on every website or application I spent longer than 5 minutes on

[image: Qbserve screenshot]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103889/discussion-on-question-by-declan-mckenna-why-do-i-feel-like-im-working-very-har).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's counterintuitive, but just because you're doing things it doesn't mean you're being productive. Being productive implies you're making progress towards some goal. The activities you've listed don't really align with one clear goal.

> A colleague once told me I have a habit of going out of scope and
>   being a bit slow, although generally I'm a bit paranoid others think
>   it too.

Certainly as developers we may see other things that may be nice to do like refactoring some code, adding more comments, etc. If you can do some of those things without increasing the scope of your ticket too dramatically, then you should consider them. Otherwise, you should note them either for yourself or add tickets to your team backlog to come back fix them.

But the point here is to try to keep your activities aligned with a single goal. When you get distracted leave yourself note to look at it after you are done with the current task.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the question, it could be that you are slow, or it could be that you perceive yourself as slow, when you really aren't.  I'm going to address the second option.

One reason you can perceive yourself to be slow is if you are not accurately estimating how much time something can take: if you think something is going to take 5 time units, and it ends up taking 13, you might feel like you are very slow compared to the estimate, but it quite possible that the estimate was wrong, and that you weren't slow at all.

You might want to work on refining your estimating skills - to get better at estimating both how much effort something requires AND how much effort you can actually get done in a work day.  For instance, assume that you **correctly** estimate that a task will require 5 days of development - that doesn't mean you will be able to deliver it in 5 days.  You need to account for reviews, planning, meetings, writing emails, updating documentation, merging code, testing, helping others, etc.  Depending on the developer, and the team, this might easily double, or more, the amount of time required to deliver it.

Then there is the question even of your initial estimate - did that 5 day estimate assume that your first design or approach was correct and that you wouldn't need to redo things? Did it assume that there would be no tricky bugs that might take significant time to solve?  Did it assume that you completely understood the task, and that you wouldn't need to spend anytime making sense of a poorly written spec or documentation?

Try to see if the issue is with your estimates, rather than your speed, and if so, start working on improving the accuracy of those estimates.

Comment: I agree. If the OP is the one who is estimating his stories, this is clearly an issue of under-estimation. OP seems to be monitoring and editing his time with an extremely fine grain, far more than would be considered normal-- even for ultra-productive people. His problem is not execution, it's estimation. Moreover, none of the things he's tried is going to address the problem of estimation in a direct way: Pomodoro remedies distraction. GTD helps people figure out *what* they should be working on. The other things like touchtyping are just negligible time tweakers.

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be three issues at play here.

There is something to be said about the fractal nature of software development itself. By fractal nature, I mean that the more you zoom in on a particular problem, the bigger the problem actually becomes. And that part isn't your fault, it's just the nature of the problem space itself. See the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox

One other issue is your perfectionism. And the last issue may be that your coworkers may just be better at putting off work that they just found out about, until it gets formally reassigned through a planning/grooming meeting either to them or to someone else.